# Get query string from Mediawiki page

Tags: query-string, mediawiki-templates, scribunto

Is there any way (like an undocumented magic word perhaps) to get the current query string (or full URL *including* query string) from within a Mediawiki template or Scribunto (Lua) module?

Comment: Typically all what determines generated content is page title.  I can't imagine any use case for checking query string.  Could you describe from user's point of view what would you like to achieve?  Possibly you took wrong approach.

Comment: I want to allow users to submit forms via GET method (for which I think I need to build an extension as the current form extensions did not appear to fit the bill) so that they can specify a subset range of paragraphs to display (using the Labeled Section Transclusion section) and then share/bookmark the result. I like the idea of keeping resolution logic accessible from templates.

Comment: The Semantic Forms extension appears to support a similar approach, but only for POST requests, and it seems a bit heftier than what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an option, consider [obtaining HTML content with API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext).  This should be simpler than writing an extension.  Of course this won't be a regular page, rather something composed client-side on blank article or server-side on non-wiki site.  With [Labeled Section Transclusion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLabeled_Section_Transclusion) extension you mentioned this should work.

Alternatively, consider some server-side post processing on generated HTML.  It should perform quite well as MediaWiki caches a lot.

AFAIK there is no magic word for checking query string and, IMO, this would be a very bad thing.  Article source is like a model in MVC pattern — you shouldn't put presentation stuff there.

Comment: I still think it would be quite convenient to have a way that people could simply add iframes to grab portions of a wiki text without additional server-side code (e.g., for excerpting literature from Wikisource). Also, I think you mean "shouldn't put controller stuff there", no? I really think the already dynamic nature of templates ought to be usable from outside the site via REST.

Comment: It's a pity the `action=render` (from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Actions ) doesn't work with a "text" argument instead of "title" (as in the API)--it shouldn't be any XSS risk as it would still be parsed.

Comment: I've submitted https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58971 toward this end.